# What is wrong with my thread-safe class using AtomicBoolean

Tags: java, thread-safety

I have a simple class that I want to test thread-safe using AtomicBoolean. it does not work if more than 2 threads tested. It throws NullPointerExcetion in doSome method in some threads: Can someone show me what I am wrong? Thanks.

```
package jcafe.common.utils;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class ThreadSafeTest {

    private final AtomicBoolean initialized = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private Object lazyObject = null;

    protected void initialize() {
        if (initialized.compareAndSet(false, true)) {

            // Some other expensive init here
            // Some other expensive init here

            this.lazyObject = new Object();
        }
    }

    public void doSome() {
        initialize();

        // NullPointerException here: this.lazyObject = null
        System.out.println(this.lazyObject.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ThreadSafeTest test = new ThreadSafeTest ();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    test.doSome();
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is why you should not write multithreaded code.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't done the locking correctly.
You ensure only 1 thread is accessing the `initialized` variable (because it is an AtomicBoolean), but once that check has happened, no more synchronization takes place.

At the moment Thread T1 comes in, checks the value of `initialized` and sets it as it is the first one there. Thread T2 could come along, check the value of `initialized` and not enter the if block. There is no guarantee however at this point that `lazyObject` has been initialized. So whilst T1 is in the sleep (so `lazyObject` is not yet set), T2 returns from the method and tries to print `lazyObject`.

The simplest way to fix this would be, don't use AtomicBoolean, make the method synchronized and make the fields volatile. Anywhere you set the values, you should do so in a synchronized block.

```
public class ThreadSafeTest {

    private volatile boolean initialized = false;

    private volatile Object lazyObject = null;

    protected synchronized void initialize() {
        if (!initialized) {
            initialized = true;                
            // Some other expensive init here
            this.lazyObject = new Object();
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Alternatively you could just set the values at construction time and make them final. If all of the fields are immutable it will be thread safe.

Comment: I can't use AtomicBoolean here? ( Not synchronized because as I know AtomicBoolean is faster than synchronized and it help the code run threadsafe too )

Comment: @Loc, AtomicBoolean ensures that only one thread can do the compare and set at any time, it doesn't provide synchronization for any other fields. You should use a synchronized block or a lock.

Comment: If we use synchronized, do we really need volatile on initialized and lazyObject fields?

Comment: @Loc yes you do. Synchronized ensures that only 1 thread can be in that block (i.e. setting the values), but other threads may have cached the old values. Using volatile ensures all other readers (threads) see the new value that was set.

Comment: Technically `lazyObject` doesn't need to be volatile *as long as all threads that access it call initialize before doing so*. The synchronized block will ensure happens-before as long as it's entered and is the only place the lazyObject variable is set.

Comment: @Radiodef true, I just didn't want to make any assumptions.

Comment: Technically in your example `initialize` doesn't need to be volatile either. But for people that are still learning I'd personally recommend to basically make everything volatile. Then when other bugs arise they can have an easier time ruling things out.

Comment: @Radiodef As I said, I didn't want to make any assumptions. If there were any other methods that accessed those variables, it'd be safer to have them marked as volatile.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to make `initialize` operation atomic (do init logic and create new object by a single thread), so that other threads can see the result of it.

To do this, you could, for example, use `synchronized` block the way suggested by others, and not the atomic boolean. You could also use a [Lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) for that.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `initialize()` method will return immediately when another thread is currently initializing the object (because compareAndSet will return false). Hence, for some threads the object is not initialized after executing the `initialize` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your threads are executing the `initialize` at the same time and some are skipping the if test containing the init code because the `initialized` is true.

You can add synchronization around your `initialized` variable

```
protected void initialize() {
    synchronized(initialized) {
        if (initialized.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            try {
                // Some other expensive init here
                Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            this.lazyObject = new Object();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's run ok in single thread because you create instance of `AtomicBoolean` initialized with `false` and then in if statement you invoke `compareAndSet(false, true)` for first invoke it will return true. According to documentation first parameter is that you expected and second is update value:

```
true if successful. False return indicates that the actual value was not equal to the expected value.
```

So if first thread invoke `compareAndSet` the condition will be true and it will enter success block and goes sleep. Now second thread will invoke  `compareAndSet` and for it condition will be false and it will exit function and invoke `.toString` on null. Because you create instance in success block where first thread went sleep.